# Admin login laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

**I edited the store method , now the problem is that when i try to login it redirect to www.example.com/admin but it shows a NotFoundHttpException.**

The `routes.php` file

```
Route::get('/admin', 'SessionsController@create');  

Route::get('/logout', 'SessionsController@destroy');  

Route::get('profile', function()
{
    return "welcome! Your username is" . Auth::admin()->username;
});  

Route::resource('sessions', 'SessionsController', ['only' => ['index',   'create', 'destroy', 'store']]);
```

here is the controller `SessionsController.php`

```
<?php

class SessionsController extends \BaseController {

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return View::make('admins');
}


/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */

public function store()
{

    $rules = array('username' => 'required', 'password' => 'required');

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if($validator -> passes()){
        $credentials = array(
            'username' => Input::get('username'),
            'password' => Input::get('password')
        );
        if(Auth::admin($credentials,true)){
            $username = Input::get('username');
            return Redirect::to("admin/{$username}");
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('/admin')->withErrors('Username or password invalid');
        }
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('/admin')->withErrors($validator->messages());

}
}


/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    Auth::logout();

    return Redirect::home();
}
```

}

the `admins.blade.php`

```
{{Form::open(array('route' => 'sessions.store'))}}
<h1>ADMIN LOGIN </h1> 
{{Form::label('username', 'Username')}}
{{Form::text('username')}}
{{Form::label('password', 'Password')}}
{{Form::password('password')}}
{{Form::submit('Login')}}
{{$errors->first()}}

{{Form::close()}}
```

and here is the model `Admin.php`

```
    use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
    use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
    use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
    use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

    class Admin extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {


        /**
         * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

        /**
         * The database table used by the model.
         *
         * @var string
         */
       protected $table = 'admins';



    }
```

I also installed **[ollieread multiauth](https://github.com/ollieread/multiauth)** 
and here is `auth.php` file

```
    return array(

        'multi' => array(
            'admin' => array(
                'driver' => 'database',
                'model'  => 'Admin',
                'table'  => 'admins'
            ),

            'user' => array(
                'driver' => 'eloquent',
                'model'  => 'User',
                'table'  => 'users'
            )
        ),

        'reminder' => array(

            'email' => 'emails.auth.reminder',

            'table' => 'password_reminders',

            'expire' => 60,

        ),

    );
```

Comment: what is the "problem", what is the error you are running into? And welcome to stack overflow!

Comment: The problem is that login does not work , when credentials are not found in database it prints out "problem" and when you type the right credentials it redirects you to homepage . Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your admin template you set the goto url as `sessions.store` which hits `SessionsController::store` in that method you have a debug function `dd()` which is throwing that string. It get's called because `auth::attempt()` returns `false` as by your own code:

```
if($attempt) return Redirect::intended('/');
```

So the behavior is exactly doing what it should. If you are succesfully logged in, you are redirected otherwise it will dump through `dd()`

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is filter. You have to add custom error message on  `app/filter.php`

Like the following

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest('/')->with('message', 'Please login first');
        }
    }
});
```

Above code, I redirect to `/` and gave **Please login first** message.